# Are aircraft separately certified for CAT III ops for +2500 feet elevation?

Tags: aircraft-certification, autoland

Is it mandatory have separate certification for aircraft operating CAT III Operations on airports having elevation more than 2500 feet? If so do that aircraft are to carry any additional equipment?

One of our airline operator has submitted a list of their aircraft which are certified for CAT III operations at airports above 2500 feet elevation. We are yet to be equipped with CAT III, hence we would like to know if we have to have any additional ground systems to enable all aircraft to operate CAT III.

Comment: Probably, CAT III is not required at 2500 ft.

Comment: Why would there be different requirements? Can you explain your thinking?

Comment: As a really wild guess, the OP has [read](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/safety_library_items/AirbusSafetyLib_-FLT_OPS-SUPP_TECH-SEQ01.pdf) that CAT III operations require a radar altimeter (RA), and the RA activates at 2,500ft. Therefore, how can you shoot a CAT III approach if the airport is above 2,500ft? If that's the case, he's probably confusing AGL with MSL.

Comment: Dear GdD, One of our airline operator has submitted a list of their aircraft which are certified for CAT III operations at airports above 2500 feet elevation.  We are yet to be equipped with CAT III, hence we would like to know if we have to have any additional ground systems to enable all aircraft to operate CATIII.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes.** In certain jurisdictions.

Such as Europe, if it has not been demonstrated during flight testing.

This is covered in [CS-AWOS](https://www.easa.europa.eu/certification-specifications/cs-awo-all-weather-operations) / Subpart 1 (which covers Automatic Landing Systems).

> In accordance with CS–AWO 132, the effects of aerodrome conditions (e.g. elevation, ambient temperature, runway slope and ground profile under the approach path) are to be investigated and, if necessary, appropriate limitations derived for inclusion in the aeroplane Flight Manual. Guidance is given in paragraph 5.

Paragraph 5:

> Elevation and Temperature. The effects of aerodrome elevation and ambient temperature should be examined where operation is envisaged at aerodromes about 750 m (2 500 ft) or in temperatures greater than ISA + 15°C.

A performance demonstration would then be required (but not additional equipment).

Answer (score 3):

Denver International has Cat III approaches to all 4 north runways (35L/R, 34L/R), and I have never heard of any Cat III certification requirements specific to that airport. As far as I know, the answer to the question is "no," since nothing special happens at or near 2500' *MSL* that affects Cat III operations.